# Search multiple data in table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

DATABASE DESIGN for `tbl_Person`

[image]

I had it displayed on my gridview, and I have a search textbox which search only the `LastName`. Now, my question is, is it possible to search the `LastName`, `FirstName` and `MiddleName` using only one textbox? When I search `LastName` it drop downs suggestions based on database data.

My search query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Person 
WHERE textSearch LIKE '%LastName%'
```

Now, if the answer of my question is YES. How can I insert the `FirstName` and `MiddleName` in my query.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to search all criteria like first name, middle name and last name 
like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Person 
WHERE 
    FirstName LIKE '%textSearch%' 
    OR MiddleName LIKE '%textSearch%' 
    OR LastName LIKE '%textSearch%'
```

Comment: I wanted to search both at the same time using one textbox, `LastName, FirstName MiddleName` the data looks like this. I tried that query, its not working

Comment: @SuperPruuylan given example what is given input and accepted result

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the below given stored procedure at the database server and make a call to it from your application. Hope it will give you the output what you are looking for.

```
CREATE PROC uspSearchByName
@name varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM  tbl_Person WHERE (FirstName LIKE '%' + @name + '%') OR (LastName LIKE '%' + @name + '%') OR (FirstName + ' ' + LastName LIKE '%' +  @name + '%')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Get "First", "Middle" and "LastName":

```
string[] stringArray = textBox.Text.Split(' ');
```

Make a loop through the strings and pass each string[i] to the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Person 
WHERE textSearch LIKE '%PositionString0%' AND textSearch LIKE '%PositionString1%'
```